# How can I wrap an ajax request into a function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Here is my code:

```
function ajaxRequest(value, path, website){
    window[website] = $.ajax({
        url :  path,
        type : 'GET',
        data: { "name": value,
            "_token": $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
        },

        beforeSend: function(){
            if(window[website] != null) {
                window[website].abort();
            }
        },
        success: function (people) {
            return [status, people];
        },

        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
            return [status, textStatus];

        },

        timeout: 15000

    });

}
```

As you see, it's a function that sends ajax requests. I call it like this:

```
var res = ajaxRequest('Jack', 'search/twitter', 'twitter');
console.log(res);
```

It returns:

[image]

Why I don't see the result in the console? Noted that I can see the result in the console if I send that ajax out of function. *(the result is an array of data)*

How can I fix the problem?

Comment: Are you using an async call to the ajax? if yes then the value may not be available to `res` when you are printing it in console where for regular async ajax call the success function is called when the async operation is completed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function ajaxRequest(value, path, website){

        return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        window[website] = $.ajax({
            url :  path,
            type : 'GET',
            data: { "name": value,
                "_token": $('meta[name="_token"]').attr('content')
            },

            beforeSend: function(){
                if(window[website] != null) {
                    window[website].abort();
                }
            },
            success: function (people) {
                resolve([status, people]);
            },

            error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                reject([status, textStatus]);

            },

            timeout: 15000

        });
    });
}
```

then do this, to get the result:

```
ajaxRequest('Jack', 'search/twitter', 'twitter').then(function(res) { console.log(res)}, function(err){console.log(err)})`;
```

Comment: Seems nice, thank you, upvote. I will try it

Comment: I don't know why always `reject()` executes. *(not `resolve()`)*

Comment: That can only mean the Ajax call itself is failing, what is code you are getting in network trace?

Comment: Man, missed it, u r aborting the request before it is sent, it is always a reject. Why u need the before send block?

Comment: Ok, I fix the problem and it works as well now. Just I'm wondering, you have only 11 rep and lots of knowledge. how come? `:-)`

Comment: :) people who r not there in SO does not mean they don’t know anything.

Comment: You are right ..! Also do you know how [this line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uwuJr.png) prints in console? Is it printed automatically? Because I don't print it in my codes

Comment: I think Juery logs it, sorry for the earlier comment u were actually logging return value which was undefined.

Comment: Yes seems Juery logs it. Just I don't understand, what you mean by *"sorry for the earlier comment u were actually logging return value which was undefined."*

Comment: I edited the comment, which had some wrong information, thought u might have read it already.

Comment: Ah I see. And my last question: Why you have used two functions in `.then()`?  Why not `.catch()`?

Comment: .then is superset of .catch, which handles only the rejected case compared to .then which handled both.

Comment: So the second function into `.then()` is the same as `.catch()` ?

Comment: In the pure JavaScript Promise, yes, people have different styles of writing, some will just miss the second argument of then and chain the output with .catch. I have to see if this is true for node’s bluebird

Answer (score 1):

For first you haven't return anything from your function, default is undefined.

Second, your `res` will not be the result of your ajax call. Because ajax is an asynchronous call, the result which will you get is accessible only in the function `success` or `error`.

See here. You can't return this. All other logic which you need to implement based on the `data` you need to write here.

```
success: function (people) {
     // Your logic here
},
```

Comment: yes same as I thought

Comment: What's the solution? Should I use promises?

Comment: @MartinAJ you can do the operations inside the `success` handler after getting the data .

Comment: If you know promises, you can use it's `thenable` approach to get the desired result. From your function return a ajax request wrapped into the Promise and use `then`'s to continure your logic